# Entity Framework Core throwing exception on querying

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using a generic repository class in my project, so an actual concrete repository is instantiated through dependency injection:

```
services.AddTransient<IRepository<Passenger>, EntityFrameworkRepository<Passenger>>();
```

Below is the generic repository itself, notice that i'm using specification pattern for query filtering. Specification themselves just return an `Expression<TEntity, bool>` expression object.

```
public class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Find(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>()
            .Where(specification.ToExpression())
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();;
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> FindOne(Specification<TEntity> specification)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(specification.ToExpression());
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(object id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

An implementation of a specification that only return passengers with confirmed email address:

```
public class PermanentPassengerSpecification : Specification<Passenger>
{
    public override Expression<Func<Passenger, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return passenger => passenger.EmailConfirmed == true;
    }
}
```

And another that matches passengers by phone number

```
public class PassengerByPhoneSpecification : Specification<Passenger>
{
    private readonly PhoneNumber _phoneNumber;

    public PassengerByPhoneSpecification(PhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        if (phoneNumber == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Passenger, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return passenger => passenger.PhoneNumber == _phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

So, basically when i query data from the repository with FindOne method, EF Core throws this:

```
InvalidOperationException: The EF.Property<T> method may only be used within LINQ queries.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF.Property<TProperty>(object entity, string propertyName)
lambda_method(Closure , TransparentIdentifier<Passenger, PhoneNumber> )
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableAsyncIterator+<MoveNextCore>d__8.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator+<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+<FirstOrDefault_>d__165.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+TaskResultAsyncEnumerable+Enumerator+<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor+<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Taksapp.Infrastructure.Repositories.EntityFrameworkRepository+<FindOne>d__3.MoveNext() in EntityFrameworkRepository.cs
```

Any hint of how I can solve this issue?

Comment: what is `Specification<TEntity>`? what ever expression that is generating does not agree with what EF expects

Comment: It doesn't make sense because these specifications only contain expressions related to the database entities. @Nkosi

Comment: Show an example of usage

Comment: Done!! I edited the post with an example

Comment: Show the one that caused that specific error. The stack trace has `<Passenger, PhoneNumber>`. I'm trying to narrow the true case of the error

Comment: I created a gist containing all relevant code: https://gist.github.com/Henry-Keys/8c293668a1a5946fdd1c83fab9ca9fcd

Comment: I'm using a AndSpecification to combine PhoneNumber and Passenger

Comment: Quick question. Does this work anywhere else? Or is this the first time you are trying to get it to work?

Comment: @Nkosi, maybe a found out the problem. I implemented a PhoneNumber class with equality, you will note in PassengerByPhoneSpecification a use of this. Entity is not supporting this for some reason: https://gist.github.com/Henry-Keys/96b0c01f32a8ac7b8fa82d7f19f6a285

Comment: Because EF has no way of converting it to a constant for its query generation.

Comment: I used Equals method on PhoneNumber and it worked, that's weird because == operator calls Equals anyway. Thanks @Nkosi. I would appreciate further insight.

Comment: Your value/domain objects need a way to convert to constants to allow the expression to get a proper value to use when compiling the expression

Comment: when you say it works I would guess it does not throw an exception, but does it find any matches? according to your value objects when comparing object it will return false if the other type being compared is not a value object type. And I do not see you doing any implicit conversions anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception and it's matching data stored in the database. The abstract ValueObject returns false when the second operand type is different from the first operand type, an example would be comparing PhoneNumber and Address.

Comment: @Nkosi Object.GetType returns the **runtime** type of the object that is being evaluated, so you don't need to do conversions when using this method, see the code examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: But phone number scenario you are matching value in dto which I doubt is a value object with the phone number value object and that is where I think the problem is.

Comment: @Nkosi, i'm not. In reality i'm putting the values coming from the PhoneNumber dto (or view model) to a real value object first. See the first line of GetPermanentPassengerByPhoneNumber method: https://gist.github.com/Henry-Keys/8c293668a1a5946fdd1c83fab9ca9fcd

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain better what i'm not getting in your concern. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: What is the format of the phone numbers as they are stored?

Comment: They are stored as a complex object in the database:
PhoneNumber_Number: NVARCHAR
PhoneNumber_RegionCode: int

Comment: I use PhoneNumber value object throughout my domain model. I don't store phone numbers as string (although PhoneNumber's ToString formats anyway in an appropriate way)

Comment: Ok then here is the thing. with out a proper [mcve] I'm left guessing here. I don't think there is much more help I can provide. You state that `PhoneNumber's ToString` formats appropriately yet the code in the links you provided did not reflect that. The general fact is that the expressions being used to generate the queries were causing conflicts with EF and I think that is where I will rest.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the expression is comparing the entity member `Passenger.EmailConfirmed` to a constant value `true`.

```
public class PermanentPassengerSpecification : Specification<Passenger> {
    public override Expression<Func<Passenger, bool>> ToExpression() {
        return passenger => passenger.EmailConfirmed == true;
    }
}
```

However in this case

```
public class PassengerByPhoneSpecification : Specification<Passenger> {
    private readonly PhoneNumber _phoneNumber;

    public PassengerByPhoneSpecification(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        if (phoneNumber == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public override Expression<Func<Passenger, bool>> ToExpression() {
        return passenger => passenger.PhoneNumber == _phoneNumber; //<--THIS WONT WORK
    }
}
```

the expression is comparing the entity member `Passenger.PhoneNumber`, which I assume is a `string` to the local variable `_phoneNumber` which is a `ValueOject` derived `PhoneNumber`.

There is no way that Entity Framework can convert that value object in the expression to valid SQL.

The `PhoneNumber` value object has no implicit or explicit conversions so when generating the query it would most likely just call `ToString` which doesn't match any phone number.

My suggestion would be allow the value object to ability the convert to what it would be most likely compared to or at the very least modify the specification to make a valid comparison.

Lets say something like

```
public override Expression<Func<Passenger, bool>> ToExpression() {
    string formattedNumber = 
        string.Format("{0}{1}",_phoneNumber.RegionCode, _phoneNumber.Number);
    return passenger => passenger.PhoneNumber == formattedNumber;
}
```

Comment: passenger.PhoneNumber is also a PhoneNumber value object, see here: https://gist.github.com/Henry-Keys/e9e44141b5896333dd37ee1de0e80b62